# JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot with postgress Database and i'am trying to do a POST, but i have this error constantly in java RunTerminal:

```
`2023-07-03T04:12:56.439-03:00  WARN 5204 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `br.com.webcko.academia.entity.Treino` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (103)]
```

**This is my Entity TreinoExercicio.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "treinos_exercicios", schema = "public")
public class TreinoExercicio extends AbstractEntity {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_treino", nullable = false)
    private Treino idTreino;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_exercicio", nullable = false)
    private Exercicio idExercicio;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "dificuldade", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String dificuldade;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="peso", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal peso;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "series")
    private BigDecimal series;

}
```

**Abstract Entity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

        @Id
        @Getter
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Getter @Setter
        @Column(name = "dt_cadastrado", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        protected LocalDateTime dataCadastrado;

        @Getter @Setter
        @Column(name = "dt_atualizado", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        protected LocalDateTime dataAtualizado;

        @Getter @Setter
        @Column(name = "ativo", nullable = false)
        protected boolean ativo;

        @PrePersist
        private void prePersiste(){
                this.dataCadastrado = LocalDateTime.now();
                this.ativo=true;
        }

        @PreUpdate
        private void preUpdate(){
                this.dataAtualizado = LocalDateTime.now();
        }

}
```

**Entity Treino.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "treinos", schema = "public")
public class Treino extends AbstractEntity {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "codigo_ordem", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String codigoOrdem;

}
```

**Entity Exercicio.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercicios", schema = "public")
public class Exercicio extends AbstractEntity{

    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_grupo_muscular", nullable = false)
    private GrupoMuscular idGrupoMuscular;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

}
```

**TreinoExercicio.CONTROLLER:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/treinoexercicios")
public class TreinoExercicioController {

    @Autowired
    private TreinoExercicioRepository treinoExercicioRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TreinoExercicioService treinoExercicioService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> cadastrar(@RequestBody final TreinoExercicio treinoExercicio){
        try{
            this.treinoExercicioService.cadastrar(treinoExercicio);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Cadastrado");
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            return  ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**TreinoExercicioSERVICE.java:**

```
@Service
public class TreinoExercicioService {

    @Autowired
    private TreinoExercicioRepository treinoExercicioRepository;


    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void cadastrar(final TreinoExercicio treinoExercicio){
        Assert.isTrue(treinoExercicio.getIdTreino() != null,"Error campo TREINO vazio");
        Assert.isTrue(treinoExercicio.getIdExercicio() != null, "Error  campo EXERCICIO vazio");
        Assert.isTrue(treinoExercicio.getDificuldade().isBlank(), "Campo DIFICULDADE vazio");
        Assert.isTrue( treinoExercicio.getPeso() != null, "Error campo PESO invalido ou vazio");
        Assert.isTrue(treinoExercicio.getSeries() != null, "Error campo REPETICOES vazio");

        this.treinoExercicioRepository.save(treinoExercicio);
    }
```

**And this is my JSON:**

`{"idTreino":103,"idExercicio":1,"dificuldade":"gfdgfd","peso":"4324","series":"434"}`

**AND THIS IS THE COMPLETE JSON I TRIED BUT HAVING THE SAME ISSUE:**

```
{
    "idTreino":{
        "id": 52,
        "dataCadastrado": "2023-07-03T02:52:10.719673",
        "dataAtualizado": "2023-07-03T02:56:48.691866",
        "ativo": true,
        "codigoOrdem": "BBB"
    },
    "idGrupoMuscular":{
        "id": 1,
        "dataCadastrado": "2023-07-02T16:54:39.44769",
        "dataAtualizado": null,
        "ativo": true,
        "nome": "a"
    },
    "dificuldade": "aaaa",
    "peso": "20",
    "series": "20"

}
```

The postman returns this error: Error Error TREINO field empty

Comment: You have `"idTreino":103` which is mapping on `private Treino idTreino;`  `Treino` is not an `int`

Comment: @ScaryWombat, it's because inside my Training entity, I still have an Abstract extends, which has an ID for all entities. I believe

Comment: In you abstract entity you have `id` but not `idTreino`, so my comment remains

Comment: oooh thanks, I'm already so tired solving these problems that I didn't touch this possibility, thank you, I'll test and get back. @ScaryWombat

Comment: Returning early kk, when i do a GET in postman in TREINO, i recive this exactly json: "idTreino":{
        "id": 52,
        "dataCadastrado": "2023-07-03T02:52:10.719673",
        "dataAtualizado": "2023-07-03T02:56:48.691866",
        "ativo": true,
        "codigoOrdem": "BBB"
    },   Why this returning id is null in a GET, but here he returns normaly as a long?( Yes, it's other object)